# Given isosceles triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DBF$ (all spherical chords), identify the chord $\overline {DF}$ so that $|AD| = |DF| = |FC|$

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d, spheres, polyhedra

**tl;dr**: As shown in the image below, find the chord $\overline {DF}$ so that $|\overline {AD}| = |\overline {DF}|$, and have the answer be in the form of the ratio between $|\overline {AC}|$ and $|\overline {DF}|$. Ideally, I'm actually looking for a slightly different ratio (which is explained below), but this is the basic problem I believe that needs to solved. Only the isosceles triangle $\triangle ABC$ may be used as input  (the image is slightly misleading, as they all should be straight lines and $\overline DF$ should be slightly higher than $\triangle ABC$ and not intersecting it).

[image]

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is to subdivide a dodecahedron into smaller faces (known as a chamfered dodecahedron), and approximate a sphere using that polyhedron. This is done in 3 steps:

1. Scale down each face from its center by some scale factor (what I'm trying to solve for) so that the hexagons constructed in the next step are planar (they will not be equiangular, however)
2. Construct hexagons in between the newly subdivided faces (goldberg polyhedrons will always have 12 pentagons, no matter how subdivided they are)
3. Scale the new face from the origin so that each vertex has the same magnitude of the original face (this is done by normalizing each vertex, then scaling by a specified radius - this will make the hexagons non-planar)

My problem is that I'm stuck on how to identify how to scale factor in the first step, as there doesn't seem to be a linear relationship between the scale factor needed and the number of subdivisions that are performed. This is shown in the two images below, where I'm adding the new faces over the original dodecahedron (radius of 1 in my case). I manually calculated **approximately** $0.40706$ (or $40.706\%$) for the first subdivision, which allowed the construction of the [green] hexagon to have satisfyingly equivalent sides. However, when I tried scaling the new pentagons again with the same scale factor (shown with the yellow pentagons), the hexagons in-between were not equilateral...

[image][image]

I suspect that the scale factor will change the more I subdivide these faces - indicating that there must be a non-linear relationship between side length and the length of the connecting chord. To attempt to solve my problem, I reconstructed the issue to what I hope is a solvable math problem, shown in the images below (although lines $\overline {AB}$ and $\overline {BC}$ should be chords, not arcs - thanks to @Blue in the comments). However, I frankly have no idea where to start... I feel like solving this problem is beyond my knowledge. I then tried condensing this to a simpler case with an isosceles triangle in 2D space, but I encountered a similar block as well. I know that I need "scale" as the output (specifically when scale was used in the first step), and my known values are the pentagon/hexagon side lengths, its position in 3D space, and the magnitude of each of the points. I would be very grateful for your guidance on this issue!

[image][image]

## Edit:

This is the result I'm trying to achieve, using the following manually approximated scale factors (note that the hexagons are not planar):

```
Subdivision | Pentagons | Hexagons 
------------|-----------|---------
     0      |     -     |    -   
     1      |  0.40706  |    -   
     2      |  0.44950  |  0.4874 
     3      |    ...    |   ...
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your first figure and usage of "spherical" are misleading, as the full description makes clear that you don't intend $\triangle ABC$ to have curved sides as in [spherical geometry.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry). Also, the term ["midsegment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint#Triangle) is typically reserved for the segment joining the *midpoints* of two sides of a triangle, which, again, is not what you intend.

Comment: Your goal seems to simplify to "Given chord $AC$ of a sphere, find $D$, $F$, $P$, $Q$ on that sphere so that $ADFCPQ$ is a planar (and thus necessarily cyclic) hexagon with $AD=DF=FC$ and $CP=PQ=QA$". If so, then at the first iteration, symmetry across $AC$ makes the hexagon fully *regular*, "balancing" on $AC$ as a diameter. However, regular hexagons would seem to pose a problem for your subdivision, because three of them balancing on edges adjacent to a vertex of the dodecahedron cannot also share edges with each other. (For that, they'd need to be planar, as in the honeycomb tessellation.)

Comment: @Blue My apologies with the terminology, finding the right words to use with my lack of knowledge was difficult - especially with "midsegment", as I didn't know the term for a line joining two sides of a triangle.

Comment: @Blue However, I am confused on two things: why is "spherical" misleading? Aren't the triangles in my images projected onto a sphere? Which leads into the second issue: why does an issue with regular hexagons matter? If you take the dual of a subdivided icosahedron (except for one subdivision, which just gets you a dodecahedron), you can certainly have 3 planar hexagons that share the same vertex - even though each of the side lengths might be slightly different, as you described with how $AD=DF=FC$ and $CP=PQ=QA$. All I need to care about is how to get $\overline DF$ based on $\triangle ABC$

Comment: The ratio of lengths of *chords* $DF$ & $AC$ is very different from the ratio of lengths of *arcs* $DF$ & $AC$. If you're interested in chords, then drawing arcs is a distraction. ... As for the hexagons ... First, to clarify my earlier remark: "For [three regular hexagons to share a vertex & edges], they'd need to be *co-planar w/each other* [because the sum of the angles at the vertex would be $360^\circ$]." It's true that three *non-regular* hexagons can share a vertex & edges, but as I wrote: symmetry in your first iteration leads to *regular* hexagons, hence the problem.

Comment: @Blue Ah, I understand your first point now - thank you so much for that clarification! I edited my question to reflect my new understanding, hopefully it more accurately presents the issue at hand. As for your second point, I'm still confused as to how "symmetry [across $AC$] in [my] first iteration leads to regular hexagons, hence the problem." Why is this a problem? These first-iteration hexagons may be equilateral but they aren't equiangular (which would occur even if I were to take the dual of an icosahedron) which allows 3 of these non-co-planar hexagons to share edges at the same vertex

Comment: *"These first-iteration hexagons may be equilateral but they aren't equiangular"* ... A polygon that is both equilateral *and cyclic* (having all vertices on a circle) is necessarily regular.

Comment: @Blue I hadn't thought about defining regular polygons like in that way, but it makes sense: if the vertices are equiangular, then they must be cyclic (like a rectangle's vertices are cyclic without being equilateral) - but regardless, the vertices of these first-iteration hexagons *aren't* on a circle... points $A$ and $C$ have slightly greater radii than the others. As such, even though they aren't co-planar with each other, isn't it possible for 3 of these hexagons to share adjacent edges at the same vertex?

Comment: *"the vertices of these first-iteration hexagons aren't on a circle... points $A$ and $C$ have slightly greater radii than the others"* ... My (mis?)understanding is that hexagon $ADFCPQ$ should be planar, & that its vertices should lie on the sphere; thus, the vertices lie within the intersection of some plane and that sphere —a circle— making the hexagon cyclic (and therefore problematically regular at the first iteration). If $A$ & $C$ *aren't* on a circle with the others, then either they aren't on the plane or aren't on the sphere, in which case, I just don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Blue Wow, thank you so much for your patience with me - I completely understand the issue now. In my attempt to solve this conundrum, I discovered that the polyhedron I'm creating is not, in fact, a truncated icosahedron, but rather a chamfered dodecahedron... which led me to this on wiki: "If the vertices are not constrained to a sphere, the polyhedron can be constructed with planar equilateral (but not in general equiangular) faces." I hadn't realized that this was an either-or situation...

Comment: I adjusted the question to better reflect the problem - I acknowledge now that the resulting faces will not be planar

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete solution but so far I have the essential conventions in place.
To make things more specific, I'll consider the sphere to have radius 1 with $B$ at the north pole, $O$ as the origin, and the points $A,D$ lying in the positive $xz$-half plane. Additionally, I'll denote
\begin{align}
\theta&=\angle ABC=\angle DBF,\\
\phi_1&=\angle BOD =\angle BOD,\\
\phi_2&=\angle AOB=\angle BOF. \\
\end{align}
(An aside: Note that these denote the arc-lengths of the various segments of the spherical figure, which is always larger than the Euclidean distance between the two vertices. This isn't crucial to the problem posed: If two pairs of vertices have the same arc-length then they have the same Euclidean distance, so we might as well consider arc-length. But it will matter if we consider ratios, since the relationship between these distance measures isn't linear.)

As such, the Cartesian coordinates for points $A,B,C,D,F$ are given as

\begin{align}
A&=(\sin\phi_2,0,\cos\phi_2),\\
B&=(0,0,1),\\
C&=(\sin\phi_2\cos\theta,\sin\phi_2\sin\theta,\cos\phi_2),\\
D&=(\sin\phi_1,0,\cos\phi_1)\\
F&=(\sin\phi_1\cos\theta,\sin\phi_1\sin\theta,\cos\phi_1),\\
\end{align}

The condition of interest is then $\angle DOF=\phi_2-\phi_1$, which is imposed by via the dot product of the position vectors for $D,F$:

$$\cos(\phi_2-\phi_1)=\cos \angle DOF=\vec{D}\cdot \vec{F}=\sin^2\phi_1\cos\theta+\cos^2\phi_1.$$
In principle, we can use $\phi_2,\theta$ to determine the angle $\phi_1\in [0,\pi]$.
Similarly, the angle $\angle AOC$ is determined via the vectors for $A,C$:

$$\cos\angle AOC = \vec{A}\cdot \vec{C}=\sin^2\phi_2\cos\theta+\cos^2\phi_2$$
which is determined by $\phi_2,\theta$ directly. So in that sense there is a functional relationship between $\phi_1$, $\phi_2-\phi_1$ and $\angle AOC$, but at present they seem...unpleasant. I'll see if I can find any clever way to reduce this. Alternatively things may simplify if we restrict to a certain case of interest. For instance, when $\theta=2\pi/5$ (as for the icosahedron) one has $\cos\theta=(2\phi)^{-1}$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. So it's plausible that a specific case may be more tractable than the generic.